# Selected azure subscription leaking over tabs on PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise, azure-powershell

I use multiple PowerShell [tabs inside of ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819501.aspx) to manage multiple subscriptions inside of Azure. Unfortunately, when I use [Select-AzureSubscription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722499.aspx) inside of one tab, all other tabs are also affected by that change. Is there a way to enforce each tab to run with a different subscription?

Comment: What happens when you open `TWO` PowerShell ISE consoles altogether? And by the way, your question got nothing to do with `Azure`.

Comment: If I have two different instances of ISE, the two act completely separate.

Comment: Now I'm confused since that sounds exactly like what you wanted? You can't have it both ways

Comment: Suppose there are two ISE windows, A and B. Each window with 2 tabs, A1, A2, B1, and B2. 
If a subscription is selected on A1, the subscription is also changed on A2, but not on B1, nor B2. 
Is it expected that different tabs on the same window will have same selected subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current subscription is session specific, and different tabs do not use different sessions.  Consider using a different AzureProfile for each tab